# Server for broadcasting RTSP video to Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I am new to video streaming and am working on a project to broadcast video to android phone over internet, and users to view the video at the same time may reach 100.

After looking around for a while I think using rtsp streaming for the phone client may be convenient(Am I right?) and so I have to choose a server, My current choice will be using

1. VLC
2. Darwin Streaming Server

Are they suitable? Or any other better choice?

How about the performance of these two servers while 100 users accessing at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Bolton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTSP streaming in H.264/AAC would be the most convenient way to reach Android devices. End-users will not need to install an app or open the stream in one - the native media player will seamlessly open the stream.

If you intend on using VLC for the encoding portion - you may want to reconsider, as I'm not sure it supports H.264/AAC compression, which is required to reach Android devices. You may want to consider using commercial software like [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wire-cast/overview.htm) or the free [Flash Media Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/.../flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) with the [AAC plugin](http://www.mainconcept.com/products/apps-plug-ins/plug-ins-for-adobe/aac-encoder.html).

Darwin Streaming Server is stable enough to handle that load (100 concurrent viewers), however the amount of throughput you have available and the bit-rate you will be broadcasting at are more important factors to consider when delivering video. In other words - your upload speed has to be able to be sufficient. If it's not intended strictly as a DIY project, I would suggest tapping into a commercial CDN's network (I would recommend [NetroMedia](http://www.netromedia.com)).

Comment: Thanks user410973, it helped a lot.　I will look into Darwin Streaming Server right away. About the network thing I think my group is already providing video service to pc, so it's not a problem. Thanks again for your suggestion:)